# How to correct redirect url with parameter and change language

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with correct redirect using htacces file. My website have 3 language PL, EN and RU. Main language is PL and it works with ex. https://mypage.domain.pl/, if I add parameter language like this https://mypage.domain.pl/?language=en then load english version.

I need something like this If i put https://en.mypage.domain.pl/ then load english version, and If I type https://mypage.domain.pl/?language=en then redirect to https://en.mypage.domain.pl/ and load english version.

I have activated wildcard on server.

This is last version, i try manually redirect

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Redirect 301 https://ru.dev.dobrestronyinternetowe.pl/ /?language=ru



</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN LiteSpeed
<IfModule Litespeed>
SetEnv noabort 1
</IfModule>
# END LiteSpeed
```

EDIT 2

I make something but it works in 50% only translate subdomain to parameters

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.dev\.dobrestronyinternetowe\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://dev.dobrestronyinternetowe.pl/?language=%1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# BEGIN LiteSpeed
<IfModule Litespeed>
SetEnv noabort 1
</IfModule>
# END LiteSpeed
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have on your htaccess file?

Comment: This is last version https://pastebin.com/ndvx3siw

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code there. For formatting help, please read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/364365

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what doesn't work but to redirect to <lang>.domain where query string contains language=<lang> you can use :

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} language=([^.]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* http://%1.dobrestronyinternetowe.pl/ [L,R]
```